# How to show all records at once in dojo dgrid?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

We are using dojo dgrid for tables in our web app. Generally, we use dgrid pagination but in one case we don't want to use pagination and show all records at once.

I followed steps as mentioned in the following URL. But its not working. There is no error but it just don't show any records when I use SingleQuery.

http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/single_query/

Comment: What Have You Tried (tm)?  Are you sure you're looking at the tutorial for the same version of dgrid you're using?  (There's a separate version of the tutorial for 0.3.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 0.3 version. Its working now.