# How to call an event when the dojo dgrid has been rendered completely?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

We are using dojo without pagination and showing all records at once. We need to call a java script method when the entire grid has been rendered completely, so that the grid rows and cell can be used for DOM manipulation.

I am trying following code, but its not working.

```
aspect.after(grid,"dgrid-refresh-complete",function(){

});

grid.on("dgrid-refresh-complete", function(event){

});
```

Comment: Is this in the context of the SingleQuery mixin like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701456/how-to-show-all-records-at-once-in-dojo-dgrid?

Comment: Yes. Its the same mixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dgrid-refresh-complete` is implemented specifically in `OnDemandList` and `Pagination`.  If you're using the `SingleQuery` mixin instead (as in the tutorial for [0.3](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.3/single_query/) or [0.4](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/single_query/)), it should be feasible to institute the same kind of event as follows:

```
var self = this;

// existing code from refresh...

// when(...) (via dojo/when) should only be necessary here for dgrid 0.3
var promise = when(this._trackError(/* existing code from refresh */));

promise.then(function () {
    on.emit(self.domNode, 'dgrid-refresh-complete', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false,
        grid: self
    });
});

return promise;
```

So, for example, in 0.3, SingleQuery's `refresh` method would look like this:

```
refresh: function () {
    var self = this;

    // First defer to List#refresh to clear the grid's
    // previous content
    this.inherited(arguments);

    if (!this.store) {
        return;
    }

    var promise = when(this._trackError(function () {
        var queryOptions = self.get('queryOptions'),
            results = self.store.query(
                self.query, queryOptions);

        return self.renderArray(
            results, null, queryOptions);
    }));

    promise.then(function () {
        on.emit(self.domNode, 'dgrid-refresh-complete', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: false,
            grid: self
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: For dgrid 0.3 you might need to use dojo/when to wrap the `_trackError` call, since it doesn't always return a promise prior to using dstore for 0.4.  I'll update the example.

Comment: I am using dgrid 0.3. What will be the exact code for dgrid 0.3?

Comment: I tried to spell this out pretty straightforwardly, but I've edited the response again to add exactly what following my instructions on top of the SingleQuery mixin code from the tutorial would yield.  I've tested this myself and it works for me.  If it still doesn't work for you, you'll need to post more details on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I am using aspect.after() but this function is not getting called. I have my own js code which i need to execute once all data is loaded.

Comment: `aspect.after` will not work for DOM events, which is what this is emitting...  you need to be using `dojo/on` (or `grid.on`).  e.g. `grid.on('dgrid-refresh-complete', function () { ... });` (you can also listen higher up in the DOM with `dojo/on` since the event will bubble)